# Exporting Data to Word Doc using IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2 fails

Tags: c#, iis, ms-word, windows-server-2008-r2

> *Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00020906-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 8001010a The message filter indicated that
>   the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A
>   (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER)).*

I get the above error message on my Windows 2008 Server R2 when I try to export data to a Microsoft Word Doc. The same works fine in my local IIS server. I've tried setting permission to everyone on my server machine. Is there anything else I need to check? It was previously working fine.

Comment: Do you have lots of Word processes sitting open on the server when you look at the task manager?

Comment: @Nanhydrin At the moment the Task Manager shows around 30 odd word processes.

Comment: Presumably they shouldn't be there. I'd suggest that you try killing a few, or all of them and see if that helps. If it does help though you'll need to revisit your code so it's releasing the Word object and closing it properly.

Comment: Thanks @Nanhydrin. Closing the active processes worked. The code looks fine to me. I tried debugging on local IIS and the word object is closed every time. But is there way I can use the active word processes rather than creating new word objects if there are active processes?

Comment: There could be a prompt that's occurring on the server that's not showing up on your local one and preventing the close. You can usually suppress the prompts with parameters to the save and close methods. I don't know off the top of my head if you can use the existing process, you probably wouldn't want to in case there's already an export under way.